# WCF service application deployment

Tags: wcf, deployment

I am newbie to WCF. I have created one WCF Service Application having three services. I want to deploy it now, so I can access it from other computers. What steps should I follow?

Again it's WCF Service application not service library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to thought that "WCF Application" cannot be deployed on IIS (Because in some articles I found that, advantage of WCF Service library over application is they can be deployed on IIS and in some other ways)

It is simple than I thought.

Just defined ABC's of service

```
<services>
  <service name="HotelBookingServiceWcf.AdminService">
    <endpoint contract="HotelBookingServiceWcf.IAdminService"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              address="mex">
    </endpoint>
   </service>
</services>
```

Went to IIS Manager
In left panel

```
Sites > Right Clieck > Add new site
```

Gave details and specified port number ok

To test it's working right click on .svc file and click on view in browser
It will open a web page if nothing's wrong you will see service page

Answer (score 1):

You can host your service on IIS as well as Windows Service. Following links might be help you.

[IIS Hosting]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx

[Windows Service]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

And try this also,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/550796/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-How-to-Host-a-WCF-Service

Comment: I am sure I mentioned that I am developing "WCF Service Application" and links you provided talks about "WCF Service Library". I know upto that "WCF Service Application" is self Hosted. Anything more than this?

Comment: Yes, you have WCF Service Application, it means it's self hosting. So when your application start WCF service will automatically start at defined IP and port from configuration file. So now you just start application and create proxy classes at client and use it. That's it.

Comment: I tried accessing my service from another machine and It's not accessible. Don't I need to make some more configurations to make this accessible?

Comment: I need to check your configuration details. Will you please provide it so that I can help you?